# Many to many relationship - retrieve both ends

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following entities set up in Code First Entity Framework:

```
 public class User
 {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
 }

 public class Task 
 {
     public int TaskId { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
 }
```

How would I write a query that for a given user, returns all tasks assigned to that user, and those tasks include all of the users that are assigned to the task.

For example:

I am assigned two tasks. Those two tasks are assigned to both me and another user.

When I retrieve my user, I want the Tasks collection to include both Tasks I am assigned to, and when I look at one of the Tasks it should have a reference back to my user, and another user.

I don't want to use lazy loading.

I tried something like:

```
 db.Users.Include(t => t.Tasks.Include(u => u.Users)).SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == 1)
```

but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the second `Include` by `Select`:

```
db.Users.Include(t => t.Tasks.Select(u => u.Users))
    .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == 1);
```

Comment: I originally tried that, but there was another error that was masking the problem. Thanks for the help.